# Scrapy "Quotes Tutorial" - Unicode in extracted text

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, scrapy

I extracted the title of a quote, following the "tutorial" in the scrapy documentation. The problem is, it gives me two unicodes at the start and the end of the title.

```
>>>quote = response.css("div.quote")[0]
>>> quote
<Selector xpath=u"descendant-or-self::div[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' quote ')]" data=u'<div class="quote" itemscope itemtype="h'>
>>> title = quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first()
>>> title
u'\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d'
>>>
```

In the documentation the extracted title looks like this:

```
>>>title
'"The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking."'
>>>
```

I`m not sure what i did wrong here, just followed the documentation. Is there something to set up in a config file or how can I fix this?
Nothing was mentioned about decode/encode unicode.

**Other Example**

I went on with the scrapy documentation, here is another example:

Scrapy Shell Input:

```
>>> for quote in response.css("div.quote"):
...     text = quote.css("span.text::text").extract_first()
...     author = quote.css("small.author::text").extract_first()
...     tags = quote.css("div.tags a.tag::text").extract()
...     print(dict(text=text, author=author, tags=tags))
```

Output snippet:

```
{'text': u'\u201cTry not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\u201d', 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u'\u201cIt is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.\u201d', 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u"\u201cI have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.\u201d", 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u"\u201cA woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.\u201d", 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
{'text': u'\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d', 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'], 'author': u'Albert Einstein'}
```

Site i scraped from:

[http://quotes.toscrape.com]

Documentation Scrapy (p.20):

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scrapy/1.2/scrapy.pdf

System:

macOS Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64

virtualenv scrapy
Python 2.7.10

**Update**

I tried the same with a new virtualenv Python 3.5.2
With Python 3.5.2 I finally get the right results, without the unicode problem like in the other setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a debug representation of the string, because you are just viewing the variable in the interpreter instead of printing it.  On Python 2.7 all non-printable, non-ASCII characters are displayed with escape codes.  In Python 3 only characters that are displayable in the current terminal encoding are displayed as escape codes.

Print the string to force display of the characters.

```
>>> s=u'\u201cThe world\u201d'
>>> s
u'\u201cThe world\u201d'
>>> print s
“The world”
```

You *may* get a `UnicodeEncodeError` if the terminal you print is using an encoding that doesn't support the non-ASCII characters, but since Python 3.5 works for you, your terminal must support them.

Note that the debug display also shows the `u` representing a Unicode string and quotes the output as well.  `print` just shows the string content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ;)